# sql query return value issue

Tags: sql-server

i am multipying the values in the query

```
DECLARE  @Rate
DECLARE @numeric
DECLARE @Result decimal
SET  @Rate= .01
SET  @Result=34750*@Rate
print @Result
```

but it always displays the value as **0**

as per my logic the result should be   **347.5**

after i get the result 347.5 i need  to spilt the values  an d insert into 2 variables
like

```
@var1= 347
@var2=5
```

what wromg i am  doing here please let me know, any help would be great

Thanks
Prince

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define scale and precision to numeric and decimal data types

You can get the whole part by casting to integer (I'm not sure if you want INT or FLOOR rounding, however). I've assumed that you just want the single most significant digit of the fraction.

```
DECLARE @Rate NUMERIC(18,4)
DECLARE @Result DECIMAL(10,1) 

SET  @Rate= .01 
SET  @Result=34750*@Rate 
PRINT @Result 

DECLARE @IntPart INT
DECLARE @FracPart INT
SET @IntPart = CAST(@Result AS INT)
PRINT @IntPart
SET @FracPart = (@Result - @IntPart) * 10
PRINT @FracPart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
DECLARE @Rate AS DECIMAL(8,2)
DECLARE @numeric AS DECIMAL(8,2)
DECLARE @Result AS DECIMAL(8,2)
SET @Rate = .01
SET @Result = 34750 * @Rate
PRINT @Result

DECLARE @First AS INTEGER
SET @First = FLOOR(@Result)
PRINT @First

DECLARE @Second AS INTEGER
SET @Second = SUBSTRING(CAST((@Result-@First) AS VARCHAR),3,1)
PRINT @Second
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined your numeric and decimal as non-floating-point numbers

You need these types for it

```
decimal(x,y)
numeric(x,y)
```

where y - is an amount of digits AFTER the comma, and x - overall amount of digits in the number

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE  @Rate decimal(18,4)
DECLARE @numeric decimal
DECLARE @Result decimal(18, 4)
DECLARE @Var1 int, @Var2 decimal(18, 4)
SET  @Rate= .01
SET  @Result=34750*@Rate
SET @Var1 = @Result
SET @Var2 = @Result - @Var1
print @Result
print  @Var1
print  @Var2
```

Output

```
347.5000
347
0.5000
```